# How to assign each variable a partner variable?

Tags: javascript

Sorry, if the title doesn't make too much sense, it's just that i don't even know what my problem is to begin trying to solve it. This code was meant to execute a function every second for 10 times that adds a div element, gives it a class, gives it a starting left position and starts moving it left. I've succeeded to create the div, give it a class and append it but where the problem comes in is making it move left.

I wanted to move it by having a variable that keeps track of the div left attribute, subtracting from that variable and always setting the divs left attribute to be equal to that variable, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly because all created divs follow one of that position tracking variable.

```
setInterval(function() {

    var Count = 0;
    var createddiv = document.createElement("div");
    var divX = 1000;

    if (Count < 1000) {

        Count = Count + 100;
        createddiv.classList.add("NewDiv");
        createddiv.style.left = divX + "px";
        document.body.appendChild(createddiv);

        divX = divX - 100;
        createddiv.style.left = divX + "px";

    }

}, 1000)
```

Comment: I guess you want the `variable` out of the `function`. You initialize it every second anew.

Comment: But that will make all created divs go exactly the same

Comment: Then you want an `array`.

Comment: AjAX, how do i apply arrays in my case?

Comment: what is NewRgn?

Comment: It was a mistake, i meant createddiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to move div from right to left in 10 seconds

JS

```
(function() {

    var Count = 0;
    var divX = 1000;
    var createddiv;

        var intervalRef = setInterval(function() {
        if (Count < 1000) {
        if(createddiv !== undefined) {
            createddiv.parentNode.removeChild(createddiv);  
        }
        createddiv = document.createElement("div");
        Count = Count + 100;
        createddiv.classList.add("NewDiv");
        createddiv.style.left = divX + "px";
        document.body.appendChild(createddiv);

        divX = divX - 100;
        createddiv.style.left = divX + "px";

        } else {
        clearInterval(intervalRef);
      }
    }, 1000);

})();
```

CSS

```
.NewDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

Here is working demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71ayyojL/)

Suggestion instead of creating new div every time, add one div and change it's left property.